# Android Studio - XML Characters encoding

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, character-encoding, special-characters

I am working in the layout files with XML have a TextView that must contain several special characters like "‡", "oe", "ƒ"... (even my browser failed to display them correctly, so I don't know if you got them right)

**how can I write those characters in XML ??**

**will they be displayed correctly in android devices ??**

Answer (score 1):

Whenever this happens, I just uninstall the apk from the device itself and then try installing again using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal window write "adb kill-server",and then run app again or uninstall the app from the phone and run again